# Why when useQuery function is called "Invalid hook call"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to call useQuery() function, innate to react-admin, inside a custom component, the preceding error appears. I am totally confused I and I can't figure out what to do. The error is clear enough I just don't know how to tackle it. I tried to visit the website in the error message and followed the instructions but I still couldn't manage to make it out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FolkMe from './Folkme';
import Settings from './Settings';
import Times from './Times';
import Controller from './Controller';
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';
import { useQuery, Loading, Error } from 'react-admin';




export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.audioBeep = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      breakLength: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultBreakLength, 10),
      sessionLength: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultSessionLength, 10),
      timeLabel: 'Session',
      timeLeftInSecond: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultSessionLength, 10) * 60,
      isStart: false,
      timerInterval: null
    }

    this.onIncreaseBreak = this.onIncreaseBreak.bind(this);
    this.onDecreaseBreak = this.onDecreaseBreak.bind(this);
    this.onIncreaseSession = this.onIncreaseSession.bind(this);
    this.onDecreaseSession = this.onDecreaseSession.bind(this);
    this.onReset = this.onReset.bind(this);
    this.onStartStop = this.onStartStop.bind(this);
    this.decreaseTimer = this.decreaseTimer.bind(this);
    this.phaseControl = this.phaseControl.bind(this);
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    this.submitTime = this.submitTime.bind(this);
  }

  onIncreaseBreak() {
    if (this.state.breakLength < 60 && !this.state.isStart) {
      this.setState({
        breakLength: this.state.breakLength + 1
      });
    }
  }

  onDecreaseBreak() {
    if (this.state.breakLength > 1 && !this.state.isStart) {
      this.setState({
        breakLength: this.state.breakLength - 1
      });
    }
  }

  onIncreaseSession() {
    if (this.state.sessionLength < 60 && !this.state.isStart) {
      this.setState({
        sessionLength: this.state.sessionLength + 1,
        timeLeftInSecond: (this.state.sessionLength + 1) * 60
      });
    }
  }

  onDecreaseSession() {
    if (this.state.sessionLength > 1 && !this.state.isStart) {
      this.setState({
        sessionLength: this.state.sessionLength - 1,
        timeLeftInSecond: (this.state.sessionLength - 1) * 60
      });
    }
  }

  onReset() {
    this.setState({
      breakLength: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultBreakLength, 10),
      sessionLength: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultSessionLength, 10),
      timeLabel: 'Session',
      timeLeftInSecond: Number.parseInt(this.props.defaultSessionLength, 10) * 60,
      isStart: false,
      timerInterval: null
    });

    this.audioBeep.current.pause();
    this.audioBeep.current.currentTime = 0;
    this.state.timerInterval && clearInterval(this.state.timerInterval);
  }



  loadData(profileId){ 
    // console.log(this.props);
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({ 
    type: 'getOne',
    resource: 'profiles',
    payload: { id: 1 }
});

console.log(data);
  }

  submitTime() {
    let timeDoneSoFar = (this.state.sessionLength * 60) - this.state.timeLeftInSecond;

  }

  onStartStop() {
    this.submitTime();

    if (!this.state.isStart) {
      this.setState({
        isStart: !this.state.isStart,
        timerInterval: setInterval(() => {
          this.decreaseTimer();
          this.phaseControl();
        }, 1000)
      })
    } else {
      this.audioBeep.current.pause();
      this.audioBeep.current.currentTime = 0;
      this.state.timerInterval && clearInterval(this.state.timerInterval);

      this.setState({
        isStart: !this.state.isStart,
        timerInterval: null
      });
    }
  }

  decreaseTimer() {
    this.setState({
      timeLeftInSecond: this.state.timeLeftInSecond - 1
    });
  }

  phaseControl() {
    if (this.state.timeLeftInSecond === 0) {
      this.audioBeep.current.play();
    } else if (this.state.timeLeftInSecond === -1) {
      if (this.state.timeLabel === 'Session') {
        this.setState({
          timeLabel: 'Break',
          timeLeftInSecond: this.state.breakLength * 60
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          timeLabel: 'Session',
          timeLeftInSecond: this.state.sessionLength * 60
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    this.loadData(this.props.profileId);
    return (
      <div className="pomodoro-clock">

        <Settings
          breakLength={this.state.breakLength}
          sessionLength={this.state.sessionLength}
          isStart={this.state.isStart}
          onDecreaseBreak={this.onDecreaseBreak}
          onDecreaseSession={this.onDecreaseSession}
          onIncreaseBreak={this.onIncreaseBreak}
          onIncreaseSession={this.onIncreaseSession}
        />

        <Times
          timeLabel={this.state.timeLabel}
          timeLeftInSecond={this.state.timeLeftInSecond}
        />

        <Controller
          onReset={this.onReset}
          onStartStop={this.onStartStop}
          isStart={this.state.isStart}
        />

        <audio id="beep" preload="auto" src="..." ref={this.audioBeep}></audio>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See .... for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 4 stack frames were collapsed.
App.loadData
src/src/components/pomodoro/App.js:91
  88 | 
  89 | loadData(profileId){ 
  90 |   // console.log(this.props);
> 91 |  useQuery({ 
     | ^  92 |   type: 'getOne',
  93 |   resource: 'profiles',
  94 |   payload: { id: profileId }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useQuery` is meant to be used in functional component and not a function inside class component, which is why you get that error. For a class component you need to use `Query` component.

Check the [`legacy component doc`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usequery-hook) in react-admin Querying API section

```js
import { Query, Loading, Error } from 'react-admin';
...
render() {
    return <Query type='getOne' resource='profiles' payload={{ id: this.props. profileId }}>
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (loading) { return <Loading />; }
            if (error) { return <Error />; }
            return (
              <div className="pomodoro-clock">
                <Settings
                  breakLength={this.state.breakLength}
                  sessionLength={this.state.sessionLength}
                  isStart={this.state.isStart}
                  onDecreaseBreak={this.onDecreaseBreak}
                  onDecreaseSession={this.onDecreaseSession}
                  onIncreaseBreak={this.onIncreaseBreak}
                  onIncreaseSession={this.onIncreaseSession}
                />

                <Times
                  timeLabel={this.state.timeLabel}
                  timeLeftInSecond={this.state.timeLeftInSecond}
                />

                <Controller
                  onReset={this.onReset}
                  onStartStop={this.onStartStop}
                  isStart={this.state.isStart}
                />

                <audio id="beep" preload="auto" src="..." ref={this.audioBeep}></audio>
              </div>
            )
        }}
    </Query>
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot really saved the situation!